# python pandas delete row on string condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame with a column of strings and integers.
On one of the columns containing strings I want to search all the items of that column for a specific substring let say "abc" and delete the row if the substring exists. How do I do that? It sounds easy but somehow I struggle with this.
The substring is always the last three characters.
I tried the following:

```
df1 = df.drop(df[df.Hostname[-4:]== "abc"])
```

which gives me

> UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame
>   index

so I tried to modify the values in that column and filter out all values that do not have "abc" at the end:

```
red = [c for c in df.Hostname[-4:] if c != 'abc']
```

which gives me

> KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])

What do I do wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), add [`indexing with str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) if need check last `4` (`3`) chars of column `Hostname` and change condition from `==` to `!=`:

```
df1 = df[df.Hostname.str[-4:] != "abc"]
```

Or maybe:

```
df1 = df[df.Hostname.str[-3:] != "abc"]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Hostname':['k abc','abc','dd'],
                  'b':[1,2,3],
                  'c':[4,5,6]})
print (df)
  Hostname  b  c
0    k abc  1  4
1      abc  2  5
2       dd  3  6

df1 = df[df.Hostname.str[-3:] != "abc"]
print (df1)
  Hostname  b  c
2       dd  3  6
```

Also works [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) if need check last chars:

```
df1 = df[~df.Hostname.str.endswith("abc")]
print (df1)
  Hostname  b  c
2       dd  3  6
```

EDIT:

If need check in last 4 chars if `abc` and then remove rows first extract values and then use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = df[~df.Hostname.str[-4:].str.contains('abc')]
print (df1)
  Hostname  b  c
2       dd  3  6
```

EDIT1:

For default index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - python counts form `0`, so values of index are `0,1,2,...`:

```
df1 = df[df.Hostname.str[-3:] != "abc"].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: great! Thanks for your quick reply with example. Now I understand!

Comment: But maybe there has to be problem with numeric with strings, maybe aslo need `df.Hostname = df.Hostname.astype(str)` if some problem.